# Storing Viewstate in Database disables my asp:ImageButtons events

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I followed the guide [here to save my ViewState into the database](http://www.componentworkshop.com/blog/2009/06/27/advanced-net-storing-viewstate-in-a-database). I did some changes to it to fit my projects code design, but the essential parts are there. But when I implant this solution all my asp:ImageButtons events stops working, but regular asp:Buttons seems to work. Why doesn't the events from asp:ImageButtons work?

Code:

```
public class DatabasePageStatePersister : PageStatePersister
{        
    //This object handles the saving and loading from database
    CiroLightLibrary.BLL.ViewState myViewState;

    public DatabasePageStatePersister(Page p, string GUID): base(p)
    {
        myViewState = new CiroLightLibrary.BLL.ViewState();
        myViewState.GUID = GUID;
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        myViewState.Load();
        this.ViewState = this.StateFormatter.Deserialize(myViewState.Value);
    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        myViewState.Value = this.StateFormatter.Serialize(this.ViewState);
        myViewState.Save();
    }
}

public class PageViewStateDatabaseStored : Page
{
    private PageStatePersister _PageStatePersister;

    protected override System.Web.UI.PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
    {
        get
        {
            if (_PageStatePersister == null)
            {
                CiroLightLibrary.BLL.ViewState myViewState = new ViewState();

                if (Request["__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE"] != null)
                    myViewState.GUID = Request["__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE"].ToString();
                else
                    myViewState.GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                _PageStatePersister = new DatabasePageStatePersister(this, myViewState.GUID);

                Literal l = new Literal();
                l.Text = "<div><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE\" value=\"" + myViewState.GUID + "\" /></div>";
                this.Form.Controls.Add(l);
            }

            return _PageStatePersister;
        }
    }
}
```

And heres a Test page:

```
public partial class test : PageViewStateDatabaseStored
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            imgButton1.CommandArgument = "1";
            btnButton1.CommandArgument = "1";
        }
    }

    protected void imgButton_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    }

    protected void imgButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Click");
    } 
}
```

Asp.net Page

```
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="imgButton_OnCommand" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton2" runat="server" OnClick="imgButton_OnClick" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="imgButton_OnCommand" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnButton2" runat="server" OnClick="imgButton_OnClick" /> 
    </form>
```

Comment: What version of .net are you using? There's a disclaimer in the blog post you mentioned: "You certainly should think twice before changing such a fundamental element of your web applications. [...]
Note that this article was originally written in 2007, and has not been tested in recent versions of .NET."

Comment: When you say, the image buttons aren't working, do you mean the events aren't firing at all, or that the commandargument isn't persisting in the viewstate and passing through?

Comment: @mamoo Im using .net 3.5

Comment: @Blake The events aren't fireing at all. I causes a postback, but no event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to override `LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()` and `SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium()` instead, and now my asp:ImageButtons also fires the events.

```
public class PageViewStateDatabaseStored : Page
{
    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        CiroLightLibrary.BLL.ViewState myViewState = new ViewState();

        if (Request["__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE"] != null)
        {
            myViewState.GUID = Request["__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE"].ToString();
            myViewState.Load();
        }

        LosFormatter myFormatter = new LosFormatter();

        return myFormatter.Deserialize(myViewState.Value);
    }

    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        CiroLightLibrary.BLL.ViewState myViewState = new ViewState();

        if (Request["__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE"] != null)
            myViewState.GUID = Request["__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE"].ToString();
        else
            myViewState.GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        LosFormatter myFormatter = new LosFormatter();
        StringWriter myStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        myFormatter.Serialize(myStringWriter, viewState);

        myViewState.Value = myStringWriter.ToString();
        myViewState.Save();

        ScriptManager.RegisterHiddenField(this, "__DATABASE_VIEWSTATE", myViewState.GUID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post.... But the answer is simply that you're saving the viewstate not the controlstate.

```
 public override void Load()
{
    myViewState.Load();
    var pair = (Pair)this.StateFormatter.Deserialize(myViewState.Value);
    this.ViewState = pair.First;
    this.ControlState = pair.Second;

}

public override void Save()
{
    myViewState.Value = this.StateFormatter.Serialize(new Pair(this.ViewState, this.ControlState));
    myViewState.Save();
}
```

Personally I'd inherit my PageStatePersister from HiddenFieldPageStatePersister then in my save method write the guid into the viewstate property and set the controlstate to null, then call the base Save method. In the Load, call the load the base.load then get the GUID from the viewstate property before pushing the db aquired values into the viewstate, controlstate properties. That way we're not modifying the control tree.... Like so:

```
public class MyPageStatePersister : System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister
{


     public MyPageStatePersister(Page page)
        : base(page)
    {
     }

    public override void Load()
    {
        base.Load();
        this.CurrentKey = (Guid)this.ViewState;
        var s = this.CurrentKey;
        var state = SomeDAOManager.GetState(s);
        if (state != null)
        {
            this.ViewState = state.First;
            this.ControlState = state.Second;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ControlState = null;
            this.ViewState = null;
        }

    }

    public Guid CurrentKey {get;set;}


    public override void Save()
    {
        if (CurrentKey == Guid.Empty)
        {
            this.CurrentKey = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        Guid guid  = CurrentKey;
        SomeDAOManager.SaveState(guid, new Pair(this.ViewState, this.ControlState));
        this.ViewState = guid;
        this.ControlState = null;
        base.Save();

    }
}
```